# What is way to fetch large json data from url?

Tags: android, json

I am fetching data from url by inputstream and appending it in string buffer like:

```
rssUrl = new URL(url);
InputStream resultStream = rssUrl.openStream();
byte[] B = new byte[8069];
for (int N; (N = resultStream.read(B)) != -1;) 
{
    String str = new String(B, 0, N);
    put.append(str);
}
resultStream.close();
```

Here in json data image is in string formate which i decode in bitmap. My problem is when above code is running , it is taken long time to fetch.

And I took screen shot where grow heap showing, it there is any other way by which I can fetch data fast.

Answer (score 1):

Use async task ,load your data in doInBackground() method, update the ui or the elements in postExecute() method,
try this [try this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Comment: I am already using Async task and dwonloading data in background and upate ui in postexcute mehod, still fetching data slow, because int data image in string

Comment: That depends on your connection speed I guess